# Ubuntu Core on isolated environments

Tags: ubuntu-core

Can Ubuntu Core run effectively in a disconnected environment?
(that is, disconnected from the internet).

How would one run security updates, software updates, upgrades, etc?

We're looking at developing some key infrastructure components for our mission-critical and highly restrictive environment and one of the key characteristics is complete internet isolation.
(We can spin up management servers, local repositories, etc and we can upload whatever packages we'd like to these server, there's no problem there).

Kind regards,
S.

Comment: It can run, but I don't know what is "run effectively" vs ineffectively.

Comment: By effectively I'm referring to the ability to push security updates other then through direct internet connection, software deployment at scale in automated, verified manner (e.g, signed), automated software upgrades from a self-curated repository inside the isolated network and basically everything you would consider enterprise-grade life cycle management of the software stack (operating system, packages, configuration, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnected is simply not a use case for Ubuntu Core.

Ubuntu Core is designed for online use. Ubuntu Core is designed to be Snap-only (no debs).

1. Snap packages, and their associated infrastructure, are designed for frequent, secure online upgrades...which does not seem like what you want.

- There is no secure offline or manual install/upgrade method. (There are offline methods, but they are hacks).
- You don't get an opportunity to audit Snap packages before they upgrade.
- You cannot easily run your own Snap repository.
- You can build your own Snaps using the Snapcraft tool...but the build will go to the public Snap Store instead of to your own private Snap repo.

2. Ubuntu Core requires your Ubuntu One ssh key during first login. There is a workaround for that, but it's an insecure hack.

For a secure alternative to Ubuntu Core for a not-on-public-network system, consider using Ubuntu Server. It's much more flexible and customizable, can be secured, and can be more easily adapted to your use case using available tools.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a detailed, coherent and useful answer.